# Java Swing event handler inside a JavaFX Application

Tags: java, swing, javafx, event-listener

I am trying to implement this barcode scanner class into my JavaFX Application so it listens for the barcode in the background. I tried the code below on a regular Java application and it worked fine but when I put it into my JavaFX application it did not work.

Is it because It's using Swing in the class and the application is FX? How would I get this class to work in my JavaFX application or are there any alternatives for it so I don't use Swing?

The class:

```
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

/**
 *   Listens for bar code input and puts it into a String Buffer.
 *
 */
public class BarcodeReader {

    private static final long THRESHOLD = 120;
    private static final int MIN_BARCODE_LENGTH = 8;

    public interface BarcodeListener 
    {
        void onBarcodeRead(String barcode);
    }

    private final StringBuffer barcode = new StringBuffer();
    private static final List<BarcodeListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<BarcodeListener>();
    private long lastEventTimeStamp = 0L;

    public BarcodeReader() {
        System.out.println("initialized");
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    if (e.getID() != KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (e.getWhen() - lastEventTimeStamp > THRESHOLD) {
                        barcode.delete(0, barcode.length());
                    }

                    lastEventTimeStamp = e.getWhen();

                     if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) 
                     {
                         if (barcode.length() >= MIN_BARCODE_LENGTH) 
                             fireBarcode(barcode.toString());

                         barcode.delete(0, barcode.length());
                     } 
                     else 
                         barcode.append(e.getKeyChar());

                    return false;
                } 
                catch (UnsupportedOperationException err) 
                {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(err); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

            }
        });

    }

    protected void fireBarcode(String barcode) {
        for (BarcodeListener listener : listeners)
        {
            listener.onBarcodeRead(barcode);
        }
    }

    public void addBarcodeListener(BarcodeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeBarcodeListener(BarcodeListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

Calling it

```
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();

reader.addBarcodeListener(new BarcodeReader.BarcodeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onBarcodeRead(String barcode) {
        System.out.println(barcode);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are not using any JavaFX class in provided code. If you need keyborad handler in JavaFX, then `Scene` class has methods: `setOnKeyPressed(EventHandler<? super KeyEvent> value)`, ` setOnKeyReleased(EventHandler<? super KeyEvent> value)`, `setOnKeyTyped(EventHandler<? super KeyEvent> value)`. You can also set key event handler to any `Node` in scene graph.

Comment: Do you mean I need FX classes in my `BarcodeReader` class or where I call it? the calling it part has other stuff that was just the code where I call it?

Comment: I mean that you provided code without any FX code and told that your FX application is not working. If it's not working then print exception stack trace or descibe in details what is wrong. Your `BarcodeListener` method `onBarcodeRead(String barcode)` is updating some JavaFX component?